# D&D dice roll python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

Trying to roll dice like in dungeons and dragon but display each roll. I dont quite know what im doing wrong and appreciate all the help.

```
from random import randint
def d(y): #basic die roll
    return randint(1, y)
def die(x, y): #multiple die roll 2d20 could roll 13 and 7 being 20 
    for [x*d(y)]:
        print (sum(int(y)))

print (die(3, 20))
```

ok so i took the advice and changed it but still recieving an error on my return line

```
#
#trying to roll dice like in dungeons and dragon but display each roll
from random import randint 
def d(sides): 
    return randint(1, sides) 
def roll(n, sides): 
    return tuple(d(sides) for _ in range(n))
def dice(n, sides):
    print (roll(n, sides))
    return sum(dice)
print(dice(3,20))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do with this line: `for [x*d(y)]:`. That is not valid syntax.

Comment: like 2*d(20) would roll a number betwwn 2 and 40 but i cant see which numbers went into it

Comment: `dice` is a function you can't sum `dice`. You need to capture the return of `roll(n, sides)` as a variable, e.g. `x = roll(n, sides); print(x); return sum(x)`. However, I don't particularly like the `print` side effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just multiple the result of a single call to `d()`, you need to make `n` different calls to the `d()`:

```
from random import randint

def d(sides):
    return randint(1, sides)

def roll(n, sides):
    return tuple(d(sides) for _ in range(n))

dice = roll(3, 20)
print(dice, sum(dice))
# (20, 18, 1) 39
```

Comment: ok so i took your advice but i stall want to make dice a class so i can write 
print (dice(3,20)) and simplify my wrinting mor this is how far i got

    #
    #trying to roll dice like in dungeons and dragon but display each roll
    from random import randint 
     def d(sides): 
        return randint(1, sides) 
    def roll(n, sides): 
        return tuple(d(sides) for _ in range(n))
    def dice(n, sides):
        print (roll(n, sides))
            return sum(dice)
    print(dice(3,20))

Answer (score 1):

Note:  This is using Python 3.6 or higher

```
from random import randint

def roll(roll)

    rolling = []

    try:
        for x in range(int(roll.split('d')[0])):
            rolling.append(randint(1,int(roll.split('d')[1])))
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'I got bungled @_@ \n Error: {err}')

    print(f'You rolled {" ".join(str(x) for x in rolling)} which has a total'
          f' of {sum(rolling)}')
```

What this function does is take in any dice roll combination (such as 3d10, 10d10, ect), and prints, using an fstring, each of the dice rolled, and then prints the combined total.

Edit: f-strings can be used to condense this down even more as necessary